# Python using GCS new client library - upload objects/'directories'

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I've been through the newest [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) for the GCS client library and went through the [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted). The sample code shows how to create a file/stream on-the-fly on GCS.

How do I **resumably** (that allows resumes if error) upload existing files and directories from a local directory to a GCS bucket? Using the new client library. IE, this (can't post more than 2 links so h77ps://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary#uploading-objects) is deprecated.

Thanks all

P.S
I do not need GAE functionality - This is going to sit on-premise and upload to GCS

Answer (score 1):

The Python API client can perform resumable uploads. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload) for examples. The important bit is:

media = MediaFileUpload('pig.png', mimetype='image/png', resumable=True)

Unfortunately, the library doesn't expose the upload ID itself, so while the upload call will resume uploads if there is an error, there's no way for your application to explicitly resume an upload. If, for instance, your application was terminated and you needed to resume the upload on restart, the library won't help you. If you need that level of retry, you'll have to use another tool or just directly invoke httplib.

The Boto library accomplishes this a little differently and DOES support keeping a persistable tracking token, in case your app crashes and needs to resume. Here's a quick example, stolen from [Chromium's system tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/boto/+/master/tests/integration/gs/test_resumable_uploads.py):

```
# Set up other stuff normally
res_upload_handler = ResumableUploadHandler(
    tracker_file_name=tracker_file_name, num_retries=3
dst_key.set_contents_from_file(src_file, res_upload_handler=res_upload_handler)
```

Since you're interested in the new hotness, the latest, greatest Python library for accessing Google Cloud Storage is probably [APITools](https://github.com/craigcitro/apitools), which also provides for recoverable, resumable uploads and also has [examples](https://github.com/craigcitro/apitools/blob/master/samples/storage_sample/uploads_test.py#L102).

Comment: I'm more interested in seeing how to upload using the latest client, mentioned in my question. Not a deprecated feature.
The doc you mentioned states 'Last updated July 17, 2012', that is a long time.
Even if 'resumable' isn't a good option here, just a working sample using this [new client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) will suffice.

Comment: I added a Boto example and also a reference to an even newer Python client.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.
Unfortunately I can't yet upvote but I'll come back and upvote later.
The issue here isn't about the 'latest' or 'hottest' tool, on the contrary, it is about a non-deprecated, **Google provided** [client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted). When working in a large enterprise you cannot rely on tools no in the docs. (Yes, I know Craig Citro is a Googler, but nevertheless).

That is all I'm looking for, a working upload example using [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted)